# Why my pyspark udf function will return None for me ?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data have some None after join, so I want to fill them with vector. For example, my data are like

```
id  value
1   [1,2,3,4,5]
2   Null
3   [1,2,3,4,5]
4   [1,2,3,4,5]
5   [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and my udf function is

```
def fillVec_5(y):
    if y:
        return y 
    else:
        return Vectors.dense([0 for i in range(5)])
getVector_5 = udf(lambda y: fillVec_5(y),VectorUDT())
df = df.withColumn('value',getVector_5(col('value'))
df.show(5,False)
```

But I will get error:

```
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 139, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 442, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1159, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: dataType.fromInternal(a)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 565, in fromInternal
    values = [f.fromInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj)]
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 438, in fromInternal
    return self.dataType.fromInternal(obj)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 619, in fromInternal
    return self.deserialize(self._cachedSqlType().fromInternal(obj))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.2-1.cdh5.11.2.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 166, in deserialize
    assert len(datum) == 4, \
TypeError: ("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()", <function <lambda> at 0x1dba938>, (None,))
```

I do not understand why my udf function will return None for me , please help me~

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: Maybe it is the reason of spark version?  I use the version of 1.6.0

Comment: This means value of `y` is None. You might want to check for len if it is not None